# How do I know which of the two time series is lagging and which is leading?

Tags: time-series, correlation, causality, lags, granger-causality

I have two time series that are highly correlated, but occasionally one moves out of line with the other. Someones the other will follow and catch up with the first. Sometimes the first will revert back.

How can I tell if one of the time series is leading the other one?

The only approach I can think of is shifting one time series by a shift of -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 and then seeing which of these shifted time series correlated best with the other time series.

This doesn't seem rigorous at all though, what is a better approach?

Comment: post your interesting time series values

Comment: What do the two time series represent?

Comment: I think you should based this on theory. Which should be the lagging and leading indicator logically. Ignoring that I would think that the leading indicator should predict the lagging one better than the lagging one predict the leading one, if they are related at all. You could calculate a MAPE for each.

Comment: The time series are prices of one asset from two different perspective. Sometimes one perspective is ahead, sometimes the other perspective is ahead. Likely one is in general "the leader". How do I find out which one?